# node.js not starting by default in Lubuntu guest running in Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu, nodejs, lxterminal

I'm using Lubuntu 14.10 in Oracle VM VirtualBox. I installed [node.js](http://nodejs.org) using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). After installation, I could run `node --version` in the same terminal and the version installed showed up. However, I could not run `node --version` or `npm --version` in the another terminal.

```
sithu@Lubuntu1410:~$ node --version
The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:
 * node
 * nodejs-legacy
 Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

sithu@Lubuntu1410:~$ npm --version
The program 'npm' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install npm
```

When I executed `nvm use stable`, it seems working.

```
sithu@Lubuntu1410:~$ nvm list
    v0.10.33
stable -> 0.10 (-> v0.10.33) (default)
sithu@Lubuntu1410:~$ nvm use stable
Now using node v0.10.33
sithu@Lubuntu1410:~$ node --version
v0.10.33
sithu@Lubuntu1410:~$ npm --version
1.4.28
```

So, my questions are:

1. can `node` be started automatically without calling `nvm use` upon every reboot and how?
2. how can I make `node` available in all terminals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run following command:

```
$ nvm alias default stable
```

Comment: It works like a charm! You saved me. Thank you.